# Docx generation - reuse

Tags: pdf-generation, docx, xdocreport

I'm looking to generate docx and pdf documents in my java application. The best, most cost effective solution seems to be xdocreport - I've started using it and it's good.

However, xdocreport doesn't seem to allow reuse of common sections across documents.

Eg.
I want to create two documents - order and invoice. Both have a customer section which should be identical. It would be nice if I could maintain a single customer template that can be applied to both documents.

Are there any libraries (free or paid) that have this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commercial product [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) can create DocX and Pdf and has an inert/merge capability meaning you can put common content into a template and merge/reference/insert with other templates.  It has a Java API and you can try the cloud service without having to install anything to see if it suits your purposes.

Please note I work for Docmosis.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to get anymore answers on this and so will mark this on as correct. It should be noted that docmosis is reliant on an install of open office which ended up being a showstopper for docmosis as a viable  solution for us.